# Prove that $\frac{AP}{PB} \frac{BQ}{QC} \frac{CR}{RD} \frac{DS}{SA}=+1$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> A transversal cuts the sides $AB,BC,CD,DA$ of a quadrilateral $ABCD$ at $P,Q,R,S$ respectively. Prove that $\frac{AP}{PB} \frac{BQ}{QC} \frac{CR}{RD} \frac{DS}{SA}=+1$.

[image: Diagram that I can think of]

I can only think of these two equations:$$\frac{BQ}{XQ} \frac{XS}{SA} \frac{AP}{PB} =+1$$ and  $$\frac{BP}{PY} \frac{YC}{RC} \frac{CQ}{QB} =+1$$
What next?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810482/prove-that-fracabpb-cdot-fracbqqc-cdot-fraccrrd-cdot-fracdssa?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply Menelaus's theorem to triangles $ABD$ and $CDB$.

Comment: Where are the Cevians? Only $DY$ is there.